# How to rename the values in the rows with their labels from an another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes, df1 has coded data and df2 has codes and their labels, I want to replace the codes with their labels in df1.

```
df1 - 
VBC  VDV
1     5
1     7
2     9
2    10

df2 - 
QCcode    Response     Label
VBC           1         Male
VBC           2        Female
VDV           5        Advertising
VDV           9        Marketing
```

I'm trying to get the output to be something similar to this:

```
df_op - 

VBC    VDV
Male    Advertising
Male    Advertising
Female  Marketing
```

Comment: I think you should explain better how your `df_op` is constructed. ¿how is `vol_percent` calculated?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**try these codes**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "VBC":[1,1,2,2],
    "VDV":[5,7,9,10]
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "QCcode":["VBC","VBC","VDV","VDV"],
    "Response":[1,2,5,9],
    "Label":["Male","Female","Advertising","Marketing"]
    })

df2_dict = df2.set_index(list(df2.columns[:2])).to_dict()

con = pd.DataFrame()
for c,part in df1.items():
    part = part.apply(lambda x: df2_dict["Label"].get((c, x)))
    con = pd.concat([con, part], axis=1)
```